# How to change the format of subparser with argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I know there is max_help_position for the main parser created with the constructor but how to change subparsers format since I have some times very long command name and I want the help message to be aligned with it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import subprocess

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="example",
                                 formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title="available commands",metavar="command [options ...]")

parser1 = subparsers.add_parser('short-cmd', help='help message')
parser1.add_argument('--path')

parser2 = subparsers.add_parser('very-long-long-name-for-a-command', help='help message')
parser2.add_argument('--path')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

output :

```
usage: test.py [-h] command [options ...] ...

example

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

available commands:
  command [options ...]
    short-cmd           create a directory for database
    very-long-long-name-for-a-command
                        create a directory for database
```

what i want :

```
usage: test.py [-h] command [options ...] ...

example

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

available commands:
  command [options ...]
    short-cmd                          create a directory for database
    very-long-long-name-for-a-command  create a directory for database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly note that there is a `max_help_position` that controls the indent for `help` lines.   The default value in the `HelpFormatter` `__init__` is `24`.

But the trick is to change that.

One way is to subclass `HelpFormatter` (or the Raw... one if you need that).

```
class MyFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def __init__(self,prog):
        super(MyFormatter,self).__init__(prog,max_help_position=55)
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=MyFormatter)
```

In theory you could create or modify a `formatter` with:

```
formatter = argparse.HelpFormatter(`prog`, max_help_position=40)
```

or

```
formatter = argparse.HelpFormatter('prog')
formatter._max_help_position = 45
```

But to do that you'd have to tweak some place within this calling tree:

```
`-h`
parser.print_help()
    parser.format_help()
        parser._get_formatter()
            parser.formatter_class(prog=self.prog)
```

(check my edit history if you think I removed something useful).

Comment: Your explanation works but do you know why it stops at 35 and do not go after (even with 120 or any large number) ?

Comment: Actual help postion is `min(self._action_max_length + 2,  self._max_help_position)`.  I'm guessing the 33 is the length of your longest `action`.